# Tagging an HTML element in Python not working

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script going using `Selenium` and on a new window pop up I am trying to retrieve this element:

```
<div class="custom-control p-2">somenumber</div>
```

The full path to this class is

```
html/body.modal-open/div#modalUserPRMLead.modal.fade.show/div.modal-dialog/div.modal-content/div.modal-body/div.row.justify-content-center.p-3/div.col-md-12/div.custom-control.p-2
```

I have tried variants of these to grab just the text of 'somenumber'

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'row justify-content-center p-3').get_attribute('innerHTML')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("html/body.modal-open/div.col-md-12./div.custom-control.p-2")).text
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("custom-control p-2")).text
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("div.row.justify-content-center.p-3")).text
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,custom-control p-2).text
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,div.custom-control.p-2).text
```

The errors I get is that it cannot locate the tag from current session. It's a new window that pops up as a result of previous script, I did `driver.current_url` just to make sure it was capturing the link to the new window in current session and it was.

I'm not understanding how to index down to the `div class` and just grab the text. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The script prior to window pop for form input was much easier because I could tag everything using `By.NAME` or `By.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS selector is wrong. XPaths don't really looks like XPaths...

Try

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="custom-control p-2"]').text
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'custom-control').text
```

In case element is dynamic you might need to apply [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

You can also check [basic syntax of XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) and [CSS-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Brilliant - first worked, thank you. I will keep reading on this/learning. Thanks a ton